# Send HTTP Request to Google Server Side

Tags: google-tag-manager, server-side, google-tag-manager-server-side

how can I send a request to Google Server Side Tag Manager Instance?

With data-tag templates from Stape.io and other tools it worked.
But I want to send out a HTTP Request from Postman or something and see it on the Debug Mode on Server Side.

I always get an 400 and see nothing in debug mode.

Maybe you can help :) Thanks

I sent a get request through Postman to my Server Side instance and expect to see the request in the debug preview mode.

Answer (score 1):

For a request to show up in the SGTM Preview Mode, it needs to have the `X-Gtm-Server-Preview` HTTP header.

To find yours, open the Preview Mode, click the three dots in the top right hand corner and click "Send requests manually".